# how to populate a dropdown in mvc and pass to controller its id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, dropdown

I have this controller action

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateTipoProyecto()
    {
        ViewBag.Categorias = _dbContext.Categoria.ToList();
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult CreateTipoProyecto(TipoProyectoDto tipoProyectoDto, Guid itemID)
    {
             //do something....    
        return View();
    }
```

And I am trying to create in my view a dropdown, where the selected value ID is received by the post action

```
 @Html.DropDownList("CategoriaId", (IEnumerable<EbanTabs.Models.Categoria>)ViewBag.Categorias)
//more things here...
//the post button here
```

What am I doing wrong? thanks

Comment: Does `TipoProyectoDto` contain a property named `CategoriaId`? And you code would throw an exception because the 2nd parameter of `DropDownList()` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, not `IEnumerable<Categoria>`

Answer (score 1):

First create a select list

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateTipoProyecto()
{
    ViewBag.Categorias = new SelectList(_dbContext.Categoria, "CategoriaId", "column for drop down items");
    return View();
}
```

in a view you create dropdown using razor and in a post action you will get id from the object like TipoProyectoDto. i use following razor syntax for my dropdown need.

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoriaId", null, "Please select category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control col-md-2"})
```

form-control and col-md-2 are css classes so they may or may not be useful to you.